# why wont my else if statement work? (the if and else work, but not the if else statement even though condition is met)

Tags: javascript, web-development-server

I cannot get the if else statement to work, the if statement and the else statement works,
I test the if else statement with an input of `115`, it doesnt work,
but if i put `135` the if statement works as it should.
I need help to fix the if else statement please!!

```js
var start = button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var lbs = input.value - 45 /*weight without the bar*/
  var add = 0

  var plates45 = 0
  var plates35 = 0

  while (lbs != add) {
    if ((add += 90) <= lbs) {
      plates45 += 2
      add += 90
      forty.innerHTML = "45lbs: " + plates45
    } else if ((add += 70) <= lbs) {
      plates35 += 2
      add += 70
      thirty.innerHTML = "35lbs: " + plates35
    } else {
      add = lbs /*to prevent infinte loop*/
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Plate Helper</h1>

<div id="container1">
  <p id="weight">Weight</p>
  <input type="text" id="input">
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <button id="button">Calculate</button>
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <center>
    <p id="result">Plates Needed</p>
    <div id="forty">
      <p id="forty_plate">45lbs: </p>
    </div>
    <div id="thirty">
      <p id="thirty_plate">35lbs: </p>
    </div>
    <div id="twenty">
      <p id="twenty_plate">25lbs: </p>
    </div>
    <div id="ten">
      <p id="ten_plate">10lbs: </p>
    </div>
    <div id="five">
      <p id="five_plate">5lbs: </p>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <p id="two_plate">2.5lbs: </p>
    </div>
  </center>
```

I refresh the page before each test so i dont think the first if statement affects the condition for the if else statement

Comment: it's painful to read without the HTML part, you have to add it in your question  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The `+=` in the `if` statements will increase the value of the `add` variable. So, within the first execution of the loop `add` will change from `0` (at the start) to `90` (at the `if` clause), and then to `180` (within the `if` when executing `add += 90`), and then to `250` (at the `else if` clause). To get the `else if` statements to execute, please try with `input.value` as a high number say 1045 (or at least above 296). And, kindly do include the HTML as noted by @MisterJojo above.

Comment: i added the HTML

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is the += operator in the if statements.
The first one `if ((add += 90) <= lbs){` first adds 90 to `add`, *then* checks if add is less than lbs. Then when it arrives at `if ((add += 70) <= lbs){`, `add` is already 90, so then it adds 70 (=160) and checks if it's less than lbs. The solution therefore would be to only add the amount (70 or 90) *if* the condition is true (i.e. replace `+=` in `if ((add += ...` to `+` but leave the lines within the blocks the qay they are).

As a side note, an alternative way to break out of your loop in the else clause would be the `break` keyword.

P.s. You come from a Python background?

Comment: yes i do come from a python background, i check the if else statement to work with a fresh page refresh with 115 as the input so the first if statement shouldnt affect the if else i dont think, i added the HTML for clarification

Comment: @Yagami_Light even if the contents of the first if block are not executed,  the if statement itself is. So `plates45 +=2` is not executed, but `(add += 90) <= lbs` is, and that has the side-effect of changing the value of `add`.

Comment: wow thanks i tested it with alert(add) and ur right! i did not know if statements worked like that thanks